Repair Arduino Nano Atmega328p 5v
I have broken Nano 328p (including Chip/Main IC Atmega328p and the Driver IC (CHXXX).
I then solder the the atmega IC, the CH IC driver and AMS1117 5 V.
When all is done, Port is known by the computer via USB (Port COM13). I also check the output power of AMS1117 5 V and its result is 4.73 V
I power the nano and the Power LED On but I didnt see fast blink on L LED (that always I see in my new nano board when plugged through USB port).
Then I try to upload a simple sketch (blink) and it failed.
I tried by pressing the button on Nano board the TX LED suddenly on.
And when the uploading progress-bar shows 70% the RX led blinks fast for less than 1 second and I think it is the same as new board when uploading a sketch (The fast blink of RX LED shows that it starts to receiver the sketch from the uploaded sketch) but then it stuck!
What could be wrong with another comnponents to make it successful to upload the sketch.
Since I'm new in this case, please let me know what should I do.
Note: 

I use atmega328p from old nano board which contains old sketch that I think I don't need to burn the bootloader.
I use the same USB cable and upload another good Nano and it worked. I also use different USB cable to make sure that the problem is not because of the cable issue.
I tried to upload the sketch using USBAsp programmer (with USBAsp Driver Module) and no luck
I also clean the pin and board surface to avoid short circuit, but no luck


Did your new AtMega328P have the appropriate bootloader burned onto it?

well, I updated my post with NOTE. I use my old nano board with old sketch on it of course. SHOULD I burn the bootloader anymore?

You shouldn't burn the bootloader on if the chip you used already has it on it.

previous output voltage at AMS1117 5v was 4.41v then I also replaced the capacitor near it and it becomes 4.73v

My mistake, all. Perhaps I burned my atmega IC when soldering using heat gun (hot air blower) since it is the first time for me using that heat gun.
Finally, I replaced to another usable atmega IC (with an old sketch in it) and soldered it again. Done! Everything is okay now and I'm able to upload a sketch successfully.
Conclusion:
For future, I'm sure the problem must be atmega IC, CHXXX IC Driver IC or the voltagge regulator.

You cannot solder using a normal heat gun of the flavour you can buy in any hardware store. You need to use a soldering rework hot air station with fine tuning of temperature and air settings. If you used a regular heat gun, you can toss that board into the electronics recycling, as any semiconductor on the board might now be damaged internally. And if you are a beginner at soldering in general it is best to start with a regular soldering iron.

you're right. I carefully solder it and it worked as expected (I use cloning board. It is expensive here and the original one is the most expensive. That's why I struggle to make it life again).
Air = 3
temperature = 400 celcius deg
(I asked my friend about that and very easy to remove the burnt board)

Brand-new Atmega MCUs don't have the Arduino bootloader on them. So if you buy one from, say, DigiKey, and then solder it into an Arduino, it won't work, because there's no software programmed into it to do anything at all.
The blank Atmega chip has to be programmed with a small piece of software called a bootloader that communicates over the serial port to allow the PC to download sketches onto the chip. The bootloader persists on the chip and when you erase a sketch, the bootloader stays intact - as it must to keep the Arduino board functional.
You can program the Atmega chip through the 6-pin ISP connector/header available on most Arduino boards and clones. A second Arduino UNO can act as a programmer - there are sketches out there that download the bootloader to a blank/corrupt Atmega MCU.
So using a good Arduino you can restore the bootloader on an Arduino with a blank MCU.
